# Android github commits to the wrong URL

Tags: android, git, github

I cannot find the setting to change this in Android studio. I just want to change the URL which android studio attempts to commit to. Currently I get a 403 error because I cannot commit to this repository (I am continuing work on an existing project which used to be stored at the URL shown).

My username and password are set correctly in settings > version control > github but I have no idea where to change this URL, it doesn't seem to be in the same place

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwW7a.png)

EDIT: Screenshot of my congif --list and remote -v. Which doesnt match the url android studio uses.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQOW3.jpg

Answer (score 3):

In android studio, you can change remote URLs without using the command line from `VCS > Git > Remotes`.

Alternatively, you can set the remote from the command line with `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:USER/REPO.git`. If you are using https, which it looks like you are, the url will be `https://github.com/USER/REPO.git`

Answer (score 1):

According to [this link here](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/), you need to open a command shell in your project directory and type this:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git
```

If you're using https, just replace the SSH url with the https url.

Comment: [link](http://imgur.com/a/n0EYr) to config screenshot. 

I have set that already and can see it in my config --list. Very confused

Comment: @MilesAdamson you should copy and paste this into your question. Be sure to select it and press Ctrl-K.